# multiple checkboxes with textfield

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I wanted to add textfield besife a checkbox like on the screenshow below , How do we show a textfield right next to a checkbox which has no label ? same on the screenshot below since the checkboxes are from a loop and I only want to show the textfield if the checkbox with no label is checked

Thanks for any idea.

#sample
[image]

#html code

```
 <div class="deal-disposition-row"></div>     
        <div class="pharmacy-checkbox">
        <mat-checkbox
         color="primary"
         style="margin-left:10px;"
         name="isAnyContingencies"
         [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.isAnyContingencies"
          >
         <div class="deal-text-label">
          Any Contingencies?
        </div>
        </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
        <span>
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let contigency of contingencies">
              <mat-checkbox 
              class="checkbox-margin"
              color="primary"
              (change)="changeCurrentContingencies($event,contigency)"
              >
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill"  *ngIf="!contigency.text; else text" matInput>
                <mat-label>Other Contingencies</mat-label>
                <input 
                  name = "buyerProposedPlans"
                  matInput
                  [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.buyerProposedPlans"
                  >
                  <span matPrefix *ngIf="dealDispositionFormFields.salePrice">$</span>
              </mat-form-field>
              <ng-template #text>
              {{contigency.text}}
              </ng-template>
              </mat-checkbox>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
    </div>
```

#ts code

```
export class DealIdleDispositionComponent implements OnInit {
  contingencies = [
    {id: 1, text: 'Financing Contigency'},
    {id: 2, text: 'Site Approval Contigency'},
    {id: 3, text: 'Permit Approval Contingency'},
    {id: 4, text: 'Tenant Approval Contingency'},
    {id: 5, text: ''},
  ]

   ......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `*ngIf` with `ng-template` to conditionally display the input text when the text is empty. Put the follwing code inside your li element.

```
<input *ngIf="!contigency.text; else text" matInput>
    <ng-template #text>
    {{contigency.text}}
    </ng-template>
```