# angular checkboxes with inputs

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Is there a way to achieve the ff design below, I have to add a textfield beside the last checkbox right now the last checkbox is not having the same distance as the other checkboxes. Can someone or does someone has an idea how to make it possible? Is CSS a solution to it?

**Design I am trying to implement**

[image: design-i-am-copying]

This is my current output based on the code below, as you can see here the last checkbox is too far from the rest

[current-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23t9H.png)

**HTML code**:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let contigency of contingencies;let i = index;">
    <mat-checkbox
      class="checkbox-margin"
      name="contigency"
      color="primary"
      [checked]="currentSelectedContingency(contigency)"
      (change)="changeCurrentContingencies($event,contigency)"
      #checkbox
    >
      <mat-form-field
        appearance="fill"
        *ngIf="contigency.text === 'Other Contingencies'; else text"
      >
        <input
          [disabled]="!checkbox.checked"
          name="otherContingency"
          matInput
          [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.otherContingency"
        />
        <span matPrefix *ngIf="dealDispositionFormFields.otherContingency"
          >$</span
        >
      </mat-form-field>
      <ng-template #text>
        <div class="deal-text-label">{{contigency.text}}</div>
      </ng-template>
    </mat-checkbox>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#ts snippet code:-

```js
contingencies = [
  {id: 1, text: 'Financing Contigency'},
  {id: 2, text: 'Site Plan Approval Contigency'},
  {id: 3, text: 'Permit Approval Contingency'},
  {id: 4, text: 'Tenant Approval Contingency'},
  {id: 5, text: 'Other Contingencies'},
]

changeCurrentContingencies(e:any,rowData:any){    
  if(e.checked){
    this.selectedContingencies.push(rowData);
  }else {
    this.removeSelectedContingency(rowData);
  }
}
```

Comment: Same question?? [multiple checkboxes with textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70205709/multiple-checkboxes-with-textfield)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let contigency of contingencies;let i = index;">
    <div [class.d-flex]="contigency.text === 'Other Contingencies'">
        <mat-checkbox class="checkbox-margin" name="contigency" color="primary"
            [checked]="currentSelectedContingency(contigency)"
            (change)="changeCurrentContingencies($event,contigency)" #checkbox>
            <div class="deal-text-label" *ngIf="contigency.text !== 'Other Contingencies'">
                {{contigency.text}}
            </div>
        </mat-checkbox>

        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngIf="contigency.text === 'Other Contingencies'">
            <mat-label>{{contigency.text}}</mat-label>
            <input [disabled]="!checkbox.checked" name="otherContingency" matInput
                [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.otherContingency" />
            <span matPrefix *ngIf="dealDispositionFormFields.otherContingency">$</span>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/5ZYqW3W still now aligned bro

Comment: share a stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src/app/checkbox-overview-example.ts

Comment: This url is not correct

Comment: I just use this one bro , this is my basis https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview

Comment: can we use this example bro https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview